# Why would a bad PCI-E power line cause the 32-pin connector to fault? (computer power supply)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, computers

I have a power supply that went bad and recently I got a tester and tested it. The tester (a Thermaltake) has multiple connector ports. You plug in the 32-pin big connector at the bottom and then can optionally plug in up to three other connectors at a time (PCI-E, molex peripheral, SATA and 4/8 pin molex CPU).

I found that all the connectors on the power supply worked, except for one PCI-E connector (undoubtedly the one that had been connected to the video card).

The weird thing is that when the bad PCI-E connector was plugged in, the 32-pin connector would fault too. I would have expected just the bad connector to fault. Also, if I plug in other connectors, they all fault if the bad connector is plugged in, but they are all good if it is not.

I have seen switched power supply schematics, but have only a very basic understanding of how they work. Maybe somebody with switched power supply experience can explain why a single bad connector would cause all the other connectors to fail?

Answer (score 2):

> I would have expected just the bad connector to fault

No, depending on the fault the whole unit goes down - PCIe power cable is +12V and GND only, but a fault like a short is supposed to trigger a protection circuit that turns everything OFF.

Otherwise, "halt and catch fire" may happen literally and not just figuratively.

Comment: Aha, so there is a "protection circuit". That is pretty interesting. How does it work?

Comment: No idea. Try to goolge some old ATX designs yourself.